# Why the objc runtime function `class_addMethod()` adds the implementation as instance and class method when the target class is `NSObject`?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

When I use objc runtime function `class_addMethod()` to inject an implementation to NSObject's instance selector, it actually inject the implementation to the instance selector **AND** the class selector:

```
@implementation HelloWorldClass
- (void) helloWorld{
    NSLog(@"hello world from instance method -helloWorld");
}
@end

// ====
// Do method injection when the application did finish launching.
Class sourceClass = objc_getClass("HelloWorldClass");
Class targetClass = objc_getClass("NSObject");
SEL helloWorldSelector = @selector(helloWorld);

Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(sourceClass, helloWorldSelector);
IMP imp = method_getImplementation(method);
const char *methodTypeEncoding = method_getTypeEncoding(method);

class_addMethod(targetClass, helloWorldSelector, imp, methodTypeEncoding);
```

Now we just declare the interface of `helloWorld` via Objc Category, and invoke the `helloWorld` message to both `NSObject` instance and class:

```
// Declare the interface for `helloWorld
@interface NSObject (HelloWorld)
+ (void) helloWorld;
- (void) helloWorld;
@end


// Send the `helloWorld` message to NSObject class
NSLog(@"Send the `helloWorld` message to NSObject class");
[NSObject helloWorld];

// Send the `helloWorld` message to NSObject instance
NSLog(@"Send the `helloWorld` message to NSObject instance");
[[NSObject new] helloWorld];
```

Although you just injected the `helloWorld` implementation to the NSObject instance selector via `class_addMethod()`, but both class and instance messages are resolved after injection:

```
=> Send the `helloWorld` message to NSObject class
=> hello world from instance method -helloWorld
=> Send the `helloWorld` message to NSObject instance
=> hello world from instance method -helloWorld
```

After testing, I found that `class_addMethod()` adds the implementation to both class and instance selectors only when the target class of `class_addMethod()` is `NSObject`.

Is it a bug for objc-runtime or Cocoa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, it's not a bug. It's defined (albeit obscure) behavior of the runtime system.

Just as every instance has an `isa` instance variable that points to it's class, every class structure in memory has an `isa` member that points to its *metaclass*. And just as any given class contains metadata about its instances -- including the list of methods that instances respond to -- the class's metaclass contains metadata about the class itself, including the list of methods that the *class* responds to.

In addition, every class structure has a `superclass` member that points to its superclass, which is mirrored in the metaclass hierarchy (i.e., each metaclass's `superclass` is another metaclass).

There's one major difference though: the superclass of `NSObject` is `nil`, while the superclass of the `NSObject` metaclass is `NSObject`. In other words, `NSObject`'s metaclass inherits `NSObject`'s instance methods. As a consequence, Objective-C classes not only respond to their defined class methods, they also respond to `NSObject` instance methods.

Confused yet? Greg Parker wrote an excellent blog that includes a very helpful diagram illustrating how this is all wired together:

[Hamster Emporium archive - Classes and metaclasses](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html)

**Edit**

Alas, the internets. If the browser you're currently using doesn't display inline PDF documents, here's a link directly to the diagram:

[Hamster Emporium archive - class diagram](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/class%20diagram.pdf)

Comment: Is this possible to add implementations ONLY to the instance method list of `NSObject`? Is there any benefit to inject to both `NSObject` class and instance methods when using `class_addMethod()`?

Comment: Your code *is* adding implementations only to the instance method list, but `NSObject`'s metaclass inherits all of its instance methods; the behavior you described is a consequence of that. To the best of my knowledge, adding the same method as a class method wouldn't make any practical difference. You could try pinging [Greg Parker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/881456/greg-parker) for a more definitive answer though.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer and comment. But I still don't understand why `NSObject`'s metaclass should inherit all of its instance methods. Hope [Greg Parker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/881456/greg-parker) could answer that. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is an existential or a practical one. Do you mean 'why' in the sense of "Why did the designers of the language make that particular choice?"

Comment: YES, I wonder "Why did the designers of the language make that particular choice".

Comment: In order for an Objective-C class to be the target of messages, it also has to be capable of properly performing instance behavior. Therefore the  method list in its metaclass has to have not only class methods, but also the instance methods that define fundamental object behaviors such as `respondsToSelector:`, etc.

Comment: @李岡諭 The reason is that without that ou would have mass of duplicate code. Take into account: 1. A root object does not have an (outer) state. So potentially every instance method can run on a class object. 2. Many of the capabilities of an instance object has to be build in to a class object, too: Messaging, introspection, … Why should one write that code twice?